# Same height and vertical align for "a" element

Tags: css

I have this **[Page](http://temporal-1.d246.dinaserver.com/derecho-penal/)** where you can see a bunch of buttons which are 'a' elements.

I need them to have the same height and set the text in the middle. Note that some of them have more than one line of text, then 'line-height' will not work.

I tried this, but not working:

```
.et_pb_button_module_wrapper .a {
    height: 200px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.et_pb_button_module_wrapper .a{
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
    min-height:100px;
    justify-content:center
}
```

just use flexbox method and min-height as above.

Answer (score 0):

You can align things in various way one of the good way is using table layout.

```
.et_pb_button_module_wrapper{
    display: table-row; 
    height: 100px;
}
.et_pb_button_module_wrapper .a{    
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    line-height: 1.2;
}
```

table-cell can align it's content in vertical.